Por que formulas de base de datos en excel me devuelven el error #¡VALOR?
hice un formulario en VBA, donde un usuario mediante una interfaz(UserForm) ingresa un registro que se vuelca en una tabla(nombre Dates), el registro se hace perfectamente, tome el encabezado de la tabla para hacer los criterios(nombre criteriosdates) y cuando quiero usar una formula de BD ejemplo
BDCONTAR (=BDCONTAR(Dates;"Peso entrada";criteriosdates)

me sale #¡VALOR!, el nombre de campo es un valor numérico. Anteriormente habia hecho en otro trabajo, un borrador para practicar eso y tanto el registro como las formulas funcionaban perfectamente, intente en otra hoja en blanco hacer una tabla(esta vez de manera manual sobre la planilla de excel)por curiosidad y me sale #¡VALOR! También. Si alguien tiene una idea de donde estoy fallando y me puede decir se lo agradecería muchísimo!

Sin datos de ejemplo concretos es difícil reproducir el problema, pero normalmente el error VALOR suele salir cuando se asigna un tipo de dato incorrecto. Por ejemplo, se espera un número y le pasas un texto. Asegúrate que las variables son del tipo adecuado. Que tú veas un número no significa que VBA lo esté reconociendo como numérico.

Gracias por responder, es una tabla simple que se usa como base de datos,
Codigo, Fecha, Empresa, Contacto, C/Nombre, C/Apellido, DNI, Patente, Malla, Peso entrada, Peso salida, Destino, Imagen; Esos son los campos(columnas), utilizo "Peso entrada"(que constate que es numérico) para nombre de campo de las formulas de base de datos, el mismo encabezado de tabla para los criterios(sacando Imagen) y la tabla se llama "Dates", y me sigue dando el mismo resultado, haciendo otra tabla en otra hoja en blanco me sigue pasando lo mismo.

Por favor, lee Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable y no olvides leer ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?. Visita también el  tour

Hola, te recomiendo que puedas compartir datos de la tabla que estás utilizando, puede ser al menos unos 2 o 3 registros, con unicamente las columnas que necesitamos conocer y datos aleatorias para no exponer tus datos reales. De momento, puedes revisar que el campo esté en formato general para que acepte el uso de formulas en vez de númerico. Más de eso, con la información que nos compartes es un poco complicado ayudarte.

Tu problema radica en la manera en que llamaste la tabla como rango de la formula.
Por ejemplo al utilizar DBCONTAR(Dates,"Fecha",criteriosdates) estás indicando que la base de datos es la tabla Dates, pero no se especifica que debe de tomar todos los valores que la misma contiene.
Para que la formula tenga el resultado esperado, debes indicarle a la formula DBCONTAR que debe de tomar todos los datos de la tabla de esta manera:
DBCONTAR(Dates[#Todo],"Fecha", criteriosdates)

Puedes conocer un poco más sobre el tema en el siguiente link: Referencias estructuradas
Espero te haya sido de ayuda.
Saludos.

Hola Eduardo, muchas gracias por responder, espero haberte entendido, probé asi: =BDCONTAR(Dates[#All];"Peso entrada";criteriosdates), y no me funciono. Tengo otros borradores donde practique estas formulas sin problemas, ahora quiero hacer lo mismo en otras hojas y tengo este error jaja.

Hola, lamento la confusión, puedes intentar remplazando el All por Todo, olvidé que tu trabajas con el excel en español, si no te funciona me comentas. =BDCONTAR(Dates[#Todo];"Peso entrada";criteriosdates)

Funciona, muchas gracias Eduardo, me salvaste!.

Con todo gusto, si la respuesta fue de ayuda te agradezco marcarla como resulta para que otros miembros sepan que fue la solución, saludos.

listo, mil disculpas porque a parte de ser novato en programación soy novato aca tambien jaja.


Tambien intente poniendo el rango de los criterios.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
